# dealing with a null date field

Tags: datetime, xpages

I have a date field on an XPage, this control may contain a date or be blank. In a repeat control I have this code:

```
var doc:NotesDocument = detailData.getDocument();
var sDate = doc.getItemValue("ACAutoStart");
doc.recycle()
return "Start Date = " + sDate
```

If ACAutoStart contains a date then it is displayed as [10/10/2013 12:34:15 AM MDT] if it is blank it displays as []. As I understand it the [] indicates that the result is an array but if I try using sDate[0] there is an error. I can't use getItemValueDateTime as it does not like the null return. How do I get this into a simple string value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your last line with `return "Start Date = " + sDate.firstElement()`.

`doc.getItemValue()` returns an object of class `java.util.Vector`. As it is not an Array you get the first element with `firstElement()` instead of `[0]` .

UPDATE:

As you mentioned in your comment it has to work also for empty values and you added try:

```
    var sDate = "";
    try {sDate = doc.getItemValue("ACAutoStart").firstElement()} catch (e) {};
    return "Start Date = " + sDate
```

Comment: Thanks: that works great if there is a value in the field ACAutoStart, however if the field is blank it chokes on it, so var sDate = doc.getItemValue("ACAutoStart").firstElement() returns just the date String if there is one but fails if the field is blank. So it sounds like a catch 22 that I need to know if there is a value there before I try to get the value.

Comment: I added a try around the the doc.getItemValue("ACAutoStart").firstElement() thena catch that sets sDate = "" in the catch. This works because I then need to use the value for sDate in some further formating and output so the firstElement solution works to get the actual date and the catch lets it pass through as null. My javascript is improving but it's got a long way to go. 16 -17 years of Notes Domino @Formula and LS but not much JS. I'm almost at the point where I like JS :-)

Comment: Same here :) - I am developing with Notes Domino since 1992 starting with release 2 - Currently, I develop 80% of my time with Java back-end functionality and 20% XPages including JavaScript for UI - that's fun!

Answer (score 0):

...just as another way (returns converted NotesDateTime to Date):

```
function getJavaDateData(doc:NotesDocument, field:string)
{
var item:NotesItem = doc.getFirstItem(field);

if (item != null){
    var dt:NotesDateTime = item.getDateTimeValue();
    if (dt != null){
        return dt.toJavaDate();
    }       
}

return null;
}
```

Off-course need to be adapted for your logic...